How to print a self-referencing cell in a list?
I'm trying to understand and/or name something.
Here is the code:
nums1 = [1, 2, 3]
nums2 = [1, 2, 3]
nums1.append(nums2)
print(nums1)
print(nums1[2])
print(nums1[3])
print("----")

nums = [1, 2, 3]
nums.append(nums)
print(nums)
print(nums[2])
print(nums[3])

When executed I get the following output:
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
3
[1, 2, 3]
----
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
3
[1, 2, 3, [...]]

The first section is normal append and makes sense.
The second section has the [...] which is telling me that the 3rd element is a self reference, which would definitely be "complex".  What I'm unclear about is the last printed line.  Why was the total list printed here, instead of "[...]"?
I was expecting the following output:
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
3
[1, 2, 3]
----
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
3
[...]


Which one is your actual question? Is it How to print a self-referencing cell in a list? or is it Why was the total list printed here, instead of "[...]"?? Title and body shouldn't disagree.

The name nums and the expression nums[3] refer to the exact same object:
>>> nums is nums[3]
True

so it stands to reason there should be no difference in what nums.__repr__ and nums[3].__repr__ return. The method doesn't care where the reference to the object came from.
Put another way, if I gave you a variable y and you observed that y is nums is true, there is no way you could determine from the list itself whether I had originally defined y with
y = nums
y = nums[3]
y = nums[3][3]
y = nums[3][3][3]
# etc

There are only 4 unique objects here: 1, 2, 3, and the list. There is no nested list, only a list that contains a reference to itself in addition to references to 1, 2, and 3.

But list.__repr__ calls repr on all its elements. The [...] and the [1, 2, 3, [...]] output are both produced by calling repr on the exact same list. So why does the same call produce different output at different times?
The answer is that list.__repr__ detects recursive calls. If a call to the same list's __repr__ method is already on the call stack, list.__repr__ just returns '[...]'. This allows it to safely avoid infinite recursion, even in more complex situations than just a list containing a reference to itself.
You can achieve similar functionality with reprlib.recursive_repr, though list.__repr__ uses a separate, C-level implementation of similar functionality.
Here's what a pure-Python implementation of list.__repr__ might look like:
import reprlib

class list:
    ...

    @reprlib.recursive_repr('[...]')
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'[{", ".join(map(repr, self))}]'


Nice, I didn't know about reprlib. You do need something to check for deeper recursion than just x is self, as in my original answer.

(Final part of answer updated by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112)

I'd mention print, as that's what they're using and not everybody knows __repr__ and what role it plays.

They should; print has nothing to do with how this works; it's just passing the string it gets from list.__repr__ to some object's write method.

On the contrary. Their question Why was the total list printed here, instead of "[...]"? is easily answered with print alone. No need to know about __repr__.

print barely even knows about the list; it doesn't care about the types of its arguments, only calling str on them in order to get strings to write.

I know. But I don't see what your point is with that...

I don't see what your point is. print has nothing to do with producing the string representation of the list.

Doesn't matter. The answer to "Why was the total list printed" simply is "Because you gave print the total list".
